# How much does the gate charge of a MOSFET change over lifetime?

Tags: charge, powermosfet, lifetime

Is the total gate charge of a silicon power MOSFET changing over lifetime, as long as it is used inside its rated operation conditions?

I am using a SIHB6N65E (650 V, 600 mOhm) were the datasheet gives me a Qg of 24 nC typical, the max value is 48 nC. I am wondering, if I need to consider even higher charges than 48nC over a couple of years.

Comment: You write this as if there's a charge trapped in the MOSFET that slowly escapes. The  gate charge \$Q_G\$ describes the amount of charge stored in the gate (to channel/ substrate = source) capactitor **when the MOSFET is switched on**. The gate-source of a MOSFET behaves like a capacitor. When switching on/off the MOSFET you're charging/discharging that capacitor. That charge isn't trapped.

Comment: If you're designing to charge the gate with "precisely" 48nC and expect that to work over a couple of years you're doing a bad job. You would normally **overdesign** so that there is some **margin**. So make sure at least 2x, maybe even 4x that maximum value is applied to the gate, so at least 200 nC. However, there is no reason to assume that this MOSFET would need more than 48 nC over its lifetime as long as you don't overstress it. But to make a design **robust** you would not design to be on the edge (48 nC) or even close to it unless you're **forced** to do so.

Comment: @christoph  A quick google of "aging of mosfet" turned this up on the first hit, "https://spectrum.ieee.org/semiconductors/processors/transistor-aging"  I suggest you do a bit of google yourself before posting a question that has already been adequately answered.

Comment: The charge transfer in Ciss, Coss is determined by geometry which also controls RdSOn

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie And does this value change over time?

Comment: @user253751 Can you name me **anything** that does **not** change over time except physical constants like the speed of light. So sure, it will change over time. The real question is, does it change so much that it is an issue we need to take into account?